# Change the font size of a text in a matrix table

Tags: fontsize, tikz-matrix

I have the following code of `tikz`... The font size `\huge` or `\tiny` does not work, could anyone help?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2cm, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  column 2/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  ] 
  { {\huge 123} & {\tiny 123}  \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Moreover, is it possible to change the font size just for a part of a text in a cell? For instance, `{\huge 12}3` in a cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to alter the properties of individual cells, you can use this

```
{|[font=\huge]| 123 & |[font=\tiny]|123  \\
  };
```

or use the regular style

```
row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={font=\huge}},
row 1 column 2/.style={nodes={font=\tiny}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=2cm, cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  column 2/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
  row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={font=\huge}},
  row 1 column 2/.style={nodes={font=\tiny}}
  ]
  {123 & 123  \\
  };
  %{|[font=\huge]| 123 & |[font=\tiny]|123  \\
%  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the `text height` in

```
row 1/.style = {nodes={text height=1.3ex, text depth=0}},
```

suitably to get the border correct.

## Edit:

Since you are using `math nodes`, you have to use math terms like `scriptstyle` and to make it big, you may use `scalebox`.

```
{\scalebox{2}{12}3 & {\scriptstyle 12}3  \\
  };
```

[image]

If you remove `math` from `matrix of math nodes` then `{\huge 12}3` will work.

Comment: I tried `{|[font=\huge]| 123 & |[font=\tiny]|123  \\};`, which doesn't seem to work. Moreover, is it possible to change the font size for just a part of a cell, e.g., `12` in `123`?

Comment: @SoftTimur See the edit.